# how to show four images in one line in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage

I need to create an app with screen like image1, image2, image3, image4 horizontally with some background color with these images, only by using wich field i can achieve this please help me??

it should be looks like tabbar in iphone i want to display these four images in all my screens and in the top of the screen.

Please any one provide me some code snippet. i am very new to iPhone development..

my requirement is like:

image1 ,  image2,  image3,  image4 with some background color

and then i need dropdown item.

Answer (score 1):

In ViewDidLoad, of ViewBasedProject

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"]];
[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(115, 15, 70, 70)];
[imageView setAlpha:0.5];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

and you will set four imageView and set CGRectMake co-ordinates according to that

Happy Coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to customise tabbar?

If so set alpha of TabBar to 0.02 and then put a View containing Background image and Icons images  behind the TabBar.

I did this in my recent project.